# PHP class properties without "$this"

Tags: php

Ss is possible, to access class properties inside this class methods without using "$this", like in C++?

Small example:

```
class MyClass
{
    protected $foo = 'abc';
    protected $bar = 'dca';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $foo = 'Hello';
        $bar = 'World!';
    }

    public function display()
    {
        echo $foo . ' ' . $bar;
    }
}


$MyObject = new MyClass();
$MyObject->display();
```

In result, I have notices about undefined variables.
But I'ld like to be sure - is it possible, or not?

Comment: Don't fight against the language.  PHP uses `$this` inside a class to access properties.  I've often heard complaints about this from C++ and C# devs, but PHP is PHP, not C++.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. It is not. In PHP, you have to use the `$this->` syntax to access instance variables.

Comment: Keeping with your hyper-accuracy theme, "*class* variables" is not the best term you could have picked... The scope resolution operator is used to access *static* methods and objects. If you try to access a non-static variable using `::`, a fatal error will be thrown. Accessing a non-static method with `::` won't throw a fatal error, but will throw a warning in E_STRICT

Comment: @vascowhite I edited it back out. If he wants to post it as part of his own answer, that's fine, but it's not really accurate to have the extra detail as part of my answer, even though it is correct. orourkek, make your own answer with the extra data, and perhaps the questioner should accept it with its greater information (if he feels that extra info relevant to his original question).